# How can I align my html table of images more vertically than horizontally?

Tags: html, css, optimization, mobile, html-table

[image: https://prntscr.com/ee42xy]

As seen here, The middle red square is what I'd like my site to look like, but my site shows more vertically.  This is for mobile optimization mostly so its not SUPER long to scroll on your phone.

```
    <table border="0" width="">
    <tbody>
    <tr>
    <td rowspan="4"></td>http://image.prntscr.com/image/707ada2723d64546ac988792ca63c7a7.png
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td><center><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: x-large;"><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: x-large;">Want Real Stats<br />
    Like These Clients?</span></span></center></td>
    <td><img class="alignright size-full" src="http://twittervisits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/right-arrow-icon3.jpg" /"></td>
    <td><img class="aligncenter size-full" src="http://twittervisits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/facebook-icon2.jpg" /></td>
    <td><center><a href="https://www.facebook.com/GirlyBowtiqueOfficial/"><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: x-large;">96,732<br />
    Page Likes</span></a></center></td>
    <td><img class="aligncenter size-full" src="http://twittervisits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/twitter-icon2.jpg" /></td>
    <td><center><a href="https://twitter.com/mvmtwatches"><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: x-large;">34,891<br />
    Followers</span></a></center></td>
    <td><img class="aligncenter size-full" src="http://twittervisits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/instagram-icon2.jpg" /></td>
    <td><center><a href="https://www.instagram.com/mrburgertruck/"><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: x-large;">28,796<br />
    Followers</span></a></center></td>
    <td><img class="aligncenter size-full" src="http://twittervisits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/youtube-icon2.jpg" /></td>
    <td><center><a href="https://www.youtube.com/morrismotley"><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: x-large;">9,674<br />
    Subscribers</span></a></center></td>
    <td><img class="aligncenter size-full" src="http://twittervisits.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/02/members-icon3.jpg" /></td>
    <td><center><span style="font-family: 'Comic Sans MS'; font-size: x-large;">1,384<br />
    Members</span></center></td>
    </tr>
    </tbody>
    </table>
```

Comment: A tip for question formatting: if you want to embed code block inside a list, you have to use 8 leading spaces. (It took me good 15 minutes to figure out what was wrong with your previous format.)

Comment: Even better, don't ask so many questions in a single question...

Comment: hm, I thought it was 4 leading spaces, sorry bud (:

Comment: thanks for any ideas (:  I know this is a busy place, but honestly, I never solve a problem by asking questions here.  So, I'll just quit.